# How to use CSS to style 4 blocks of Info in the homepage?

Tags: css

Ok, I want my home page to have a structure like the below picture

[image]

-The 1st block of info is just 1 "text line"

-The 2nd block of info is the "Wellcome Text" (there're many text lines in here)

-The 3rd block of info is the "Note Text" (there're some text lines in here)

-The 4th block of info is for holding a few widgets such as buttons, icon...

So, I decided to use `Div`. It works fine for the 1st, 2nd & 4th but I don't know how to position the 3rd.

```
.aTextLine
{
    position:relative;
    left:500px;
    top:32px;
    text-align:right;
    width:420px;
}

.wellcomeText
{
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
    top:50px;
    text-align:left;
    width:720px;
}

.widgetSection
{
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
    top:60px;
    text-align:left;
    width:720px;
}

.noteText
{
    position:relative;
    left:230px;
    top:60px;
    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
}
```

If i obmitted the `noteText` then it look like the picture but without the note section, so :

How to change the CSS `.noteText` so that it will look like the above picture

The home page is like this

```
    <html>
      <div class="{style.aTextLine}" > ...1 text line</div>
      <div class="{style.wellcomeText}"  > many text lines....
        .....
        ...</div>
      <div class="{style.widgetSection}" > <g:Button...> <img...> </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: I have just edited my question

Comment: Could you please share the code in a fiddle @Tum

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HFnex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/cHj3C/1/)

I assumed your html as designed in the fiidle. so modified only few css. If you want that design alone,  i can overwrite the whole code in best manner.

```
.div1
{
 position:relative;
 left: 100px;
 text-align: right;
 top:32px;
 width:420px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

.div2
{
   position:relative;
   left:80px;
 top:50px;
 text-align:left;
 width:500px;
 border: 1px solid;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
```

}

```
.div3
{   
 position:absolute;
 width:100px; 
 left: 600px;
 top: 80px;
 border: 1px solid;
 height: 100px;
}

.div4
{
  position:relative;
 left:80px;
 top:60px;
 text-align:left;
 width:500px;
 clear: both;
 border: 1px solid;
 }
```

Let me know if any problem occurs or requirement changes. I ll edit it.

[EDITED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/cHj3C/2/)
It ll not cause any problem..

Comment: but will "position:absolute" cause any problem? for example different resolution will be ok for absolute?

Comment: Then you can use my Edited fiddle.

Comment: Yes Yes, seem this is the solution, so it will work the same for any resolution or screen size right ?

Comment: Yes. Only thing is you need to specify width in percentage.I have removed your top,left,position properties. Those are not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

See for .note text you have kept kept left = 230px and 100 px width ,so totally u need 200 + 720 + 230 +100px =1250px which is too much. Probabaly reduce it to something like this :

```
.welcomeText
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 100px;
    top: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 480px;
}

.noteText
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Alternatively you could put both wellcome and note text in one div and use percentage width; something like this

```
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background: aqua;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

div#one {
        width: 75%;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }

```
div#two {
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
```

For html

```
<section>
<div class="one">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
</section>
```

you could do like this perhaps 1,2,4 in one column and then note in rest ..so all those column will have 75% and ur note 3rd div will have rest of 25%

Comment: doesn't work, the problem is that I use relative for the "noteText" so it is always stay below the "Wellcome text"

Comment: I want the Wellcome & the ATextLine to be aligned right

Comment: edited the css ..check it out ..use float left/right css property and enclose both wellcome and notetext in one div

Comment: can u make the 1st, 2nd & 4th into the main div. The outer dive will contain the main Div + the note Div?

Comment: regarding a question u have asked in above answer ..if u give width and borders in pixels ..it will mess up in different resolutions .. you should give it in % ..as u can see in above case no matter what screen width is the whole section will be 80% of screen and u can then decide how much of that 80% to distribute between the two coulumns/divs you want

Comment: check now @Tum ..if this is what u want

Answer (score 1):

To create WHOLE div for WELCOME and NOTE div after that split two separate div and use `float:left`  `float:right`

like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Uh3Z5/)

> HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div class="header">1 text line</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="welcome">The 2nd block of info is the "Wellcome Text" (there're many text lines in here)......</div>
    <div class="note">Note Text"</div>
</div>
<div class="widget">4th block of info is for holding a few widgets such as buttons, icon.</div>
```

> CSS

```
.main{
width: 1300px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.header{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #ffff00;
text-align: center;
font-size: 2em;
}
.container{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}
.welcome{
width: 75%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.note{
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
float: right;
background-color: #87cefa;
}
.widget{
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background-color: #0cbadf;
}
```

Comment: I need the ATextLine & the Wellcome aligned left

Comment: can u make the yellow part to have left align with the grey part?